# Duration calculation with negative cashflows

Tags: bond, duration

I have a pool of (mortgage) assets that pay cashflows as below. How could I correctly calculate the duration? Does it have a meaning in the sense of a vanilla/callable bond as the measure of price sensitivity?

Year  CF

0     1

1     25

2     25

3     0

4     0

5     -5

6     0

7     -5

8     5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can calculate the duration and use it as sensitivity measure, as you are used to.

That is because the npv of the cashflows is:
$NPV = \sum_i [ c_i * \exp(- y_i * t_i ) ]$

With $c_i$ the fixed cashflow amount at time $t_i$.

From that it follows, that the derivative of the NPV with respect to a parallel shift of the yieldcurve is

$d(NPV)/dy = - \sum[ c_i * t_i * \exp(- y_i * t_i ) ]$

If you divide that by the NPV, you get the definition of the duration.
You see the formulas are valid regardless of the sign or amount of the $c_i$.